# How to handle pop up websites with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting data from multiple websites and I run into this one that has a pop up on it (see image below). I have tried multiple things like checking for an alert or getting the driver's windows so I can switch to it an close it. I'm really stuck and can't seem to find a way through this. I've seen solutions but these dial with alerts. Does anyone have an idea?
[image]

Comment: Is website URL public ?

Comment: looks like an overlay div on the same/tab window.  (it's not an alert) Right-click on it and choose "inspect" to see what you need to target to click the close button.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium you can specify to wait for given element, so if this is the known popup, then:

1. Choose element within this popup
2. Wait for that element to be detected
3. Navigate to cross button and close the popup

Answer (score 0):

I tried in several ways. All of them were successful because I added `time.sleep(10)` after `driver.get('url')`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path to chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://satellitenewsnetwork.com/")
time.sleep(10) # None of the below method works if this is removed.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("ml-webforms-popup-2207054"))
# First:
closepopup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mailerlite-popup']/a")
print(closepopup.get_attribute("class"))
closepopup.click()

# Second:
# popup = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='mailerlite-popup']"))) # Tried with visibility_of_element_located too.
# print(popup.get_attribute("class"))
# closepopup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mailerlite-popup']/a")
# print(closepopup.get_attribute("class"))
# closepopup.click()

# Third:
# closepopup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mailerlite-popup']/a")
# print(closepopup.get_attribute("class"))
# driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",closepopup)
#
# Fourth:
# closepopup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mailerlite-popup']/a")
# print(closepopup.get_attribute("class"))
# ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(closepopup).click().perform()

time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```